# golang equivalent of ansi c raise()

Tags: go, signals

What is the golang equivalent of the ANSI C raise() function?

See here for an example usage of raise():

- http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/signal/raise.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the [os](http://golang.org/pkg/os/) package:

```
p, err := os.FindProcess(os.Getpid())
p.Signal(os.Interrupt)
```

Additionally, you can catch signals sent to your process using the [os/signal](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) package, which allows you to specify a channel on which to receive signals:

```
c := make(chan os.Signal)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
sig := <-c
fmt.Printf("Got %s!\n", sig.String())
```

This implementation won't work on the go playground because it won't let you import os/signal, but if you run the code locally, it should work fine (does on my machine): http://play.golang.org/p/QcrRl2BeNS

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
process,_ := os.FindProcess(os.Getpid())
process.Signal(os.Kill)
```

...where os.Kill is one of the (sadly few) standard signals defined [here](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Signal) or UNIX platform signals [here](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SIGABRT).